# Java mock a method of a private field that returns null

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock a method of a private field that has a return type of `void`. In my test, I am trying to mock `aClass.doSomething()` to throw an `IllegalStateException` and I need to verify that `recover()` is called. Here is an example:

```
public class ClassToTest implements Runnable {
   private ClassToMock aClass;

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try{
           aClass.doSomething("some parameter");
       } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
           logger.error("Something bad happened", e);
           recover();
       }
   }

   public void recover(){
      logger.info("I am recovering");
   }
}
```

I have done each piece separately:

1. Mock a method call of a private field
2. Mock a method that has `void` return type
3. Throw exception
4. Verify a private method call

but I wasn't able to put all together. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are over-tagging. Use only that mocking framework you actually want to use. Then: provide the test code you created so far. Making a mock object that throws upon a call to void method is easy basic stuff. There more interesting question is: how to get that mock into your class under test as your code doesn't show how that private field is initialized (that part should be in your question too)

Comment: I am trying all these frameworks. Each has some issues. That's why I tagged all of them that experts in each may help me. The private field is instantiated in the constructor.

Comment: Stay with Mockito. Read how to do dependency injection with constructors. That is all you need. And hint: given your example, you would probably do the verify part by mocking / verify on that logger object.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I'd elaborate GhostCat's comments:

> Stay with Mockito

Mockito is more than a mocking framework - it's a discipline. If you read carefully the documentation for Mockito and restrain yourself from resorting to PowerMock *et al* you will learn good OOP practice.

> Read how to do dependency injection with constructors

*Primum non nocere* - first refactor your code like this:

```
public class ClassToTest implements Runnable {

   private final ClassToMock aClass;
   private final Logger logger;

   //injection of collaborators through the constructor
   public ClassToTest(ClassToMock aClass, Logger logger) {
       this.aClass = aClass;
       this.logger = logger;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try{
           aClass.doSomething("some parameter");
       } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
           logger.error("Something bad happened", e);
           recover();
       }
   }

   public void recover() { //there is no need for this method to be public - see Effective Java item 13
      logger.info("I am recovering");
   }
}
```

Now your code is testable using Mockito *without resorting to more complex mocking frameworks*:

```
//mocks
@Mock ClassToMock classToMock;
@Mock Logger mockLogger;

//system under test
ClassToTest classToTest;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception { 
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();
    classToTest = new ClassToTest(classToMock, mockLogger);
}

@Test
public void whenRun_thenDoesSomethingWithSomeParameter() {       
    //act
    classToTest.run();

    //assert
    verify(classToMock).doSomething(eq("some parameter"));
}

@Test
public void givenAnIllegalStateForAClass_whenRun_thenLogsError() {       
    //arrange        
    IllegalStateException e = new IllegalStateException();
    when(classToMock.doSomething(anyString()).thenThrow(e); 

    //act
    classToTest.run();

    //assert
    verify(mockLogger).error(eq("Something bad happened"), same(e));
}

@Test
public void givenAnIllegalStateForAClass_whenRun_thenLogsRecovery() {       
    //arrange        
    when(classToMock.doSomething(anyString()).thenThrow(new IllegalStateException()); 

    //act
    classToTest.run();

    //assert
    verify(mockLogger).info(eq("I am recovering"));
}
```

Comment: @IrajHedayati thanks for the accept! Good luck with Mockito in the future!